# Call REST API from PowerShell Script

Tags: rest, powershell

How can I call a rest based API from a PowerShell script and process the Json answer?

Comment: Adam The Automater hs an excellent article on [Working with REST APIs and PowerShell’s Invoke-RestMethod](https://adamtheautomator.com/invoke-restmethod/)

Answer (score 50):

What you want is PowerShell 3 and its `Invoke-RestMethod`, `ConvertTo-Json`, and `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlets.  Your code will end up looking like:

```
 $stuff = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get;
```

and there shouldn't even be a need to invoke `ConvertFrom-Json` on the resulting `$stuff` => it's already in a usable non-string format.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/hh849971.aspx for details.

Comment: You might also need to supply credentials.  In this case you would make a command such as $stuff = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Credential "domain\username".

Comment: Is there a way to pass in the credentials for Basic Auth?  What Jubblerbug said works to present a popup asking for the password but I need to automate this

Comment: When using REST Method PUT you need to create a Body as well, see this excellent article for more help [Open Tech Guides - How to call Azure Devops REST API from PowerShell](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/azure/201/devops-rest-powershell.html)

Answer (score 22):

I created this Get-Http function to make HTTP requests

```
param([string]$url)

$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$req.Method ="GET"
$req.ContentLength = 0

$resp = $req.GetResponse()
$reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($resp.GetResponseStream())
$reader.ReadToEnd()
```

Dealing with the end result as xml is really easy, however,  if you want to process JSON you probably will need some .Net library like JSON.Net.

Answer (score 5):

We use Powershell to query a REST API that deals only with Json style data. It was awkward at first but the below code is all we need to perform most operations:

```
# Authentication
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$creds = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyUsername","MyPassword");
$webclient.Credentials = $creds

# Data prep
$data = @{Name='Test';} | ConvertTo-Json

# GET
$webClient.DownloadString($url) | ConvertFrom-Json

# POST
$webClient.UploadString($url,'POST',$data)

# PUT
$webClient.UploadString($url,'PUT',$data)
```

Comment: this is powershell you use in production to consume web services?

Comment: I was answering a specific question related to interacting with a JSON API through PowerShell.I never said I'd use this code in production.

Comment: I'm confused, you're implying that this is somehow not proper code.  IF you would not use this in production, then why not?  and why post it?

Comment: I would not use this code in production because the credentials are hard-coded into the script as plain text. They should be script parameters and should be encrypted. This is just a sample script, it doesn't do anything, so I wouldn't put it into production because it doesn't do anything, other than answer the question that was asked here.I posted this in plain text because it is a simple answer to a simple question.