# Access the Google Maps API within Powershell

Tags: google-maps, powershell

I try to program a name generator script for various sample data entry jobs. What I need to do is the following:

- Access the Google Maps Api and give me a random adress (in a specific city if possible)
- Return Street and Zip Code (and City (see above))

Is that possible in Powershell? I was thinking about using the IE ComObj and just parse the dom of Google Maps but that seems so wasteful.

Any help would be great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Google maps API however it [looks](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html) like you are just calling web services.

You can interact with web services in PowerShell. If the service communicates with SOAP you can use the [`New-WebServiceProxy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315258.aspx) cmdlet. If it is a REST service you can use the  `System.Net.WebRequest` .NET class, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574723/call-rest-api-from-powershell-script) an example. As noted in the linked answer, you will probably want a JSON library to process the service response. Also, this fella posted a [JSON module](http://poshcode.org/2098) on PoshCode that you might want to take a look at.

Also, a new cmdlet is being introduced in PowerShell V3 `Invoke-RestMethod`, which is currently in community technical preview...

Comment: Carefully read the terms of service though, the data from most of Google's Web Services must be displayed on a Google map.

Answer (score 0):

Google map provides REST API's to use them in Powershell,  you can call these using an Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet to get your task done. Infact I wrote a [Googlemaps](https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2016/05/17/powershell-module-for-google-map/) module in powershell and you can get the same from Powershell Gallery