# JIRA - Update last build number from SVN

Tags: svn, jira, build-script

I have a powershell build script which checks out code and increments a build number in SVN (nightly) in our Version.h file.

What I need is some way to set that build number in JIRA (or have JIRA read it from SVN) so that when a story is marked as resolved, it sets a "Last Version" field to that build number so QA knows which build an issue was resolved in.

What's the best way to do this? I could potentially use some combination of the JIRA CLI and a custom field or something, but I was wondering what suggestions were? Are there any scripts/plugins written for this already? I was thinking of using a custom option field and then somehow populating the dropdown with the new build number or something, but that seems like a dirty solution and I don't really know how to do it anyway.

The build number is different from the version that we have in JIRA since those versions we're using for sprints.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is probably to use [Jira's REST API](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/)  (assuming you're using Jira v4.x onwards, I think).  Jira supports SOAP as well, but I think that is going to be more bother than it is worth.

Then assuming your proxy is set correctly, you can use code similar to this Stackoverflow question:  [Call REST API from PowerShell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574723/call-rest-api-from-powershell-script).

Lastly, since the Jira REST api needs authentication, I'd suggest you **do not** include the password for obvious reasons, but read it from a secure store, or permissioned system file or some other appropriate alternative.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, thanks. But how would I change the JIRA workflow to set a custom field like that when moving from In progress->Resolved? It would seem that I need my script to set something global or project-wide field and then have the workflow grab that value when changing or something.

Comment: There seems to be a workflow transition REST call:  [http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#id2474418](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#id2474418), so it should be possible to add that into a script as well.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to transition workflows from the build script, I want to update a (global?) field from the build script and then have the workflow post action grab that value and set it when someone does a transition.

Comment: I see.  In that case, I'm not too sure.  It might be better to post the question to the atlassian forums and someone there may be able to answer.  I have a suspicion that Jira can't do that unless you write a plugin.

Comment: Yeah, that might be the case. I was thinking of using a combination of either the REST API or a CLI to set some global variable and then use a plugin (which one?) to grab that information and set a custom field or label or something.